# How can i apply loop on snapshot and append all data in ul li with its key and value?

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting data from the Firebase real-time database and I want to generate a PDF when I click the button. I get data perfectly in **snapshot**

I want to loop on this **snapshot** and show all the data in **ul li**. Anyone can help me, how can I use a loop to get snapshot data and then append that with its key and value in **ul li**?

```
    function getPDF(e) {
    firebase.database().ref('gpr/' + e.id).on('value', function (snapshot) {

        console.log(snapshot.val().key);
        console.log(snapshot.val().flightNum);
        console.log(snapshot.val().flightType);
        console.log(snapshot.val().captainName);

    });



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to use `for...in` to loop through your `snapshot` :

```
for (const property in snapshot.val()) {
    console.log(`${property}: ${snapshot.val()[property]}`);
    // will output something like: "name: John"
}
```

The above code will loop through every property of `snapshot.val()` and print its value. Its up to you to append it to appropriate component